# Embed youtube video without sound on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, iframe, youtube

After search on google and Stackoverflow, i can't find any solution. Some people write me saying that the youtube videos embebed on my website, load correctly, **but without sound on iPhone5 and some iPad's**.

I'm using this embebed iframe:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/n6ro5O1_FEs?ps=docs&controls=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I added

```
class="youtube-player" type="text/html"
ps=docs&controls=1
```

Over the normal iframe to improve click response on mobile version, without that, we need do many clicks to play video on mobile.

And this is my website http://goo.gl/oSqMFI

Best regards

Comment: I just tried your web site on an iphone 5 and there's just a blank space where you're video should be. I'm also struggling with embedding videos on iphone5